# "Resource not found" after authenticating with Facebook

Tags: facebook, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am following the instructions to [Configure App Service to use Facebook Login](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication/)

I've set up a Facebook app and set the settings as instructed. In my callback I've appended "/.auth/login/facebook/callback" to my mobile app's URL.

In the Xamarin.iOS project I am using the `WindowsAzure.MobileServices` client to call login:

```
await client.LoginAsync(current, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook)
```

I can get the Facebook login to show, but after I authenticate and grant permission, I get a page with "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable" and control is not being returned to my app.

I have configured my Mobile App to "Log in with Facebook" for unauthenticated users, so when I try to access the callback URL directly from a browser, I am directed to login with Facebook. Once log in, I am taken to https://{mymobileapp}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done#*=* with a message "You have successfully signed in"

This leads me to believe that potentially the Azure Mobile Client that I am using does not know what to do with the redirect??? I am using the [Windows Azure Mobile Services](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices) version 1.3.2 which seems to be the latest, but that was released almost a year ago.

Update: Should I be using [Azure Mobile Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client) instead? I'm confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the new App service Mobile app which is the current platform? 
If so, here is the reference on how to add facebook authentication to your xamarin ios app. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-users/

From your post it looks like you are using the new service. In that case,  Windows Azure Mobile Services version 1.3.2 will not work for you.

You should be using Azure Mobile Client SDK here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to be using Mobile Client SDK if you're using App Service.

The main difference in clients is how the redirect/callback works after successfully authenticating.

With App Service, we expect the client to be redirected to /.auth/login/facebook/callback.

With the old Mobile Service SDK, it would be watching for a redirect to /login/facebook or /signin-facebook, depending on if you're running Node or .NET respectively.

With app service, we will always redirect to /.auth/login/facebook/callback.